# awk command is working in the console but not working inside shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I'm filtering the fourth column in a file using below command. it's working fine in the console

```
[User@ipaddress Now]$ creationTime="8:15 PM"
[User@ipaddress Now]$ awk -F, -v var="$creationTime" '{if($4==var) print}' input.txt
serial1,tech,EU,8:15 PM,gan
```

Added the same command in shell script but it's not working.

```
$ cat test.sh
creationTime=$(date -d '330 minutes'  +"%l:%M %p")

echo $creationTime 
awk -F, -v var="$creationTime" '{if($4==var) print}' input.txt
```

Output while execting the script

```
[User@ipaddress Now]$ sh test.sh
8:15 PM
```

input.txt

```
serial1,tech,APAC,8:09 PM,anz
serial1,tech,EU,8:15 PM,gan
```

Comment: Since the time is calculate dynamically in the script, the timestamp might simply not being part of `input.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that `$creation_time` contains leading spaces. When you inspect it with `echo`, they might not be visible, but they will definitely not match `$4` in `awk`. Example:

```
$ creationTime=$(date -d '330 minutes'  +"%l:%M %p")
$ echo ">${creationTime}<"
> 4:50 PM<
```

Try instead:

```
creationTime=$(date -d '330 minutes'  +"%l:%M %p" | sed 's/^ *//')
```